# Sound on collision and level change (UE5)

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I have created a box collision(for falling off the platform) of simply losing a game and restarting the map. But when I add the "Open level" to the "On Component Begin Overlap", "Play Sound" does not work. Could someone help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFgd2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because after the player hits the box collision, Unreal will restart the level so fast that you will not be able to hear the sound, in order to fix this problem just add a delay node after the play sound 2d node to hear the audio, then use the open level node afterwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish it didn't delay the fall from the platform and ensured make the sound continue at the start of the new level. I think the best solution would be to add animation. I appreciate your help.